# Magento Home Page Check Out Link Change

Tags: php, magento

On a Magento cart I want to change the link on gray checkout button on the front page. I'm not sure in which directory is the file and were to change it.

Comment: Can you please clarify where is that button you are mentioning? I only see the "Checkout" link in header.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [enable template paths](http://screencastworld.com/2010/04/screencasts/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-and-add-block-name-hints). You may want to use Firebug or Google Chrome's inspector for more markup inspections, as well.